# Using Booleans in Rails to display & hide info - Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails and quite unsure how to go about the below issue, so any help or advise would be much appreciated - thank you in advance

- i have a boolean "advertise job without salary"
- when a user ticks the box [giving a true result] i would like the salary of the advert not to be displayed at the show.html.erb page
- if the user does not tick the box [giving a false result] i would like the salary of the advert to be displayed at the show.html.erb page

[image]

> i tried the below but no success - any help or advise would be much
>   appreciated:

show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>advertise without salary:</strong>
  <%= @advert.salarydisplay %>

  <% if @advert.salarydisplay == "true"  %>
    <%= "i want to advertise without salary" %>
    <%= @advert.salarystart class: "hide" %>
    <%= @advert.salaryend class: "hide" %>
  <% else %>
   <%= "i want to advertise with salary" %>
   <%= @advert.salarystart %>
   <%= @advert.salaryend %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

css file

```
.hide { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the default sqlite by any chance?

In sqlite you have to write it that way since it stores boolean as "t" and "f" (kind of a pain in the neck but eh, the more you know!)

```
<% if @advert.salarydisplay == "t"  %>
```

Edit as max pointed out, use this instead:

```
<% if @advert.salarydisplay? %>
```

also, consider refactoring and adding that logic into a helper or decorator, ideally in your view you want little to no logic :)

Comment: Better would be to use `@advert.salarydisplay?` since ActiveRecord creates interrogation methods for boolean attributes.

Comment: thanks @max `@advert.salarydisplay?` this worked: `<% if @advert.salarydisplay? %>` `<%= "i want to advertise without salary" %>` `<% else %>` `<%= "i want to advertise with salary" %>` `<%= @advert.salarystart %>` `<%= @advert.salaryend %>` `<% end %>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add / remove the fields while the user is filling out the form you need to use javascript.

```js
$('#display_salary_checkbox').on('init change', function(){
  $(this).parents('form').find('.salary-input').toggle();
}).trigger('init');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Advertise job without salary</label>
    <input id="display_salary_checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  </div>
  <div class="salary-input">
    <label>Start salary</label>
    <input type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="salary-input">
    <label>End salary</label>
    <input type="number">
  </div>
</form>
```

You will need to adapt the above to the actual selectors on your form.

But from a UX perspective why not just tell the users that they can leave the fields blank if the do not want to advertise the salary?

Comment: on a side note - use snake case for compound word attributes `salary_start` `display_salary` it's much easier to read.

Comment: Edited JS to show how you would start with it hidden.